# Kohana PHP framework Kohan_auth can't debug or use

Tags: php, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I've inherited a project, which uses the Kohana MVC framework and it's  Kohan_auth class to register someone.  When submiting registration it submits a form post to the class below.  I don't see where the ->register is used or what instance means or how to debug or solve this.  Please help.

```
   Auth::instance()->register($_POST, TRUE);
```

does not enter data and just redirects back to the registration page with no error messages.  How can I debug this, unit tests also don't work as they require older phpunit versions.

Auth::instance() seems to go to this code

```
* @package    Useradmin/Auth
* @author     Gabriel R. Giannattasio
*/
 abstract class Useradmin_Auth extends  Kohana_Auth {

/**
 * Singleton pattern
 *
 * @return Auth
 */
public static function instance()
{

    if ( ! isset(Auth::$_instance))
    {

        // Load the configuration for this type
        $config = Kohana::$config->load('auth');

        if ( ! $type = $config->get('driver'))
        {
            $type = 'file';
        }

        // Set the session class name
        $class = 'Auth_'.ucfirst($type);

        $config->set("useradmin", Kohana::$config->load('useradmin.auth') );

        // Create a new session instance
        Auth::$_instance = new $class($config);
    }

    return Auth::$_instance;               
}
}
```

which extends this

```
   abstract class Kohana_Auth {

// Auth instances
protected static $_instance;

/**
 * Singleton pattern
 *
 * @return Auth
 */
public static function instance()
{
    if ( ! isset(Auth::$_instance))
    {
        // Load the configuration for this type
        $config = Kohana::$config->load('auth');

        if ( ! $type = $config->get('driver'))
        {
            $type = 'file';
        }

        // Set the session class name
        $class = 'Auth_'.ucfirst($type);

        // Create a new session instance
        Auth::$_instance = new $class($config);
    }

    return Auth::$_instance;
}

protected $_session;
protected $_config;

/**
 * Loads Session and configuration options.
 *
 * @return  void
 */
public function __construct($config = array())
{
    // Save the config in the object
    $this->_config = $config;

    $this->_session = Session::instance($this->_config['session_type']);
}

abstract protected function _login($username, $password, $remember);
abstract public function password($username);
abstract public function check_password($password);

/**
 * Gets the currently logged in user from the session.
 * Returns NULL if no user is currently logged in.
 *
 * @return  mixed
 */
public function get_user($default = NULL)
{
    return $this->_session->get($this->_config['session_key'], $default);
}

/**
 * Attempt to log in a user by using an ORM object and plain-text password.
 *
 * @param   string   username to log in
 * @param   string   password to check against
 * @param   boolean  enable autologin
 * @return  boolean
 */
public function login($username, $password, $remember = FALSE)
{
    if (empty($password))
        return FALSE;

    return $this->_login($username, $password, $remember);
}

/**
 * Log out a user by removing the related session variables.
 *
 * @param   boolean  completely destroy the session
 * @param   boolean  remove all tokens for user
 * @return  boolean
 */
public function logout($destroy = FALSE, $logout_all = FALSE)
{
    if ($destroy === TRUE)
    {
        // Destroy the session completely
        $this->_session->destroy();
    }
    else
    {
        // Remove the user from the session
        $this->_session->delete($this->_config['session_key']);

        // Regenerate session_id
        $this->_session->regenerate();
    }

    // Double check
    return ! $this->logged_in();
}

/**
 * Check if there is an active session. Optionally allows checking for a
 * specific role.
 *
 * @param   string   role name
 * @return  mixed
 */
public function logged_in($role = NULL)
{
    return ($this->get_user() !== NULL);
}

/**
 * Creates a hashed hmac password from a plaintext password. This
 * method is deprecated, [Auth::hash] should be used instead.
 *
 * @deprecated
 * @param   string  plaintext password
 */
public function hash_password($password)
{
    return $this->hash($password);
}

/**
 * Perform a hmac hash, using the configured method.
 *
 * @param   string  string to hash
 * @return  string
 */
public function hash($str)
{
    if ( ! $this->_config['hash_key'])
        throw new Kohana_Exception('A valid hash key must be set in your auth config.');

    return hash_hmac($this->_config['hash_method'], $str, $this->_config['hash_key']);
}

protected function complete_login($user)
{
    // Regenerate session_id
    $this->_session->regenerate();

    // Store username in session
    $this->_session->set($this->_config['session_key'], $user);

    return TRUE;
}
} // End Auth
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable logging in `application/bootstrap.php`, `php.ini` and use:

```
Kohana::$log->add(Log::MESSAGE, $msg);
```

or

```
Kohana::$log->add(Log::MESSAGE, Kohana_Exception::text($e), Array(),Array('exception'=>$e));
```

see [Log::MESSAGE](https://v2docs.kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Log#constants)

BTW: take my Log class:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct script access.');

class Log extends Kohana_Log {

    public function add($level, $message, array $values = NULL, array $additional = NULL){


        if(strpos($message,'~') == FALSE) {
            $message .= ' ~ ';
        }

        if(!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']))
            $message .= " !!!  TASK";
          else
            $message .= " !!!  ($_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD])//$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        $message = strtr($message,"\r\n\t",'   ');
        if(count($_POST) > 0){
            if(isset($_POST['csrf']))
                unset($_POST['csrf']);
            if(isset($_POST['f_pass']))
                unset($_POST['f_pass']);
            if(isset($_POST['password']))
                $_POST['password'] = 'strlen() = '.strlen($_POST['password']);
            if(isset($_POST['password2']))
                $_POST['password2'] = 'strlen() = '.strlen($_POST['password2']).', pass==pass2: '.($_POST['password2'] == $_POST['password']?'tak':'nie');
            $message .= '??'.http_build_query($_POST);
        }

        if (isset($additional['exception'])){
            if($additional['exception'] instanceof HTTP_Exception_301)
                return false;
            if($additional['exception'] instanceof HTTP_Exception_302)
                return false;
            if($additional['exception'] instanceof ORM_Validation_Exception){
                $message .= "\n".print_r($additional['exception']->errors('models'),TRUE)."\n";
            }
            if($additional['exception'] instanceof GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException) {
                parent::add(self::DEBUG, 'HTTP request error [ 1 ]: :url'."\r\n".':body',[':url'=>$additional['exception']->getRequest()->getUrl(), ':body'=>$additional['exception']->getRequest()->getBody()]);
            }
            if($additional['exception'] instanceof GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException) {
                $_body = $additional['exception']->getResponse()->getBody();
                    parent::add(self::DEBUG, 'HTTP reponse error [ 2 ]: :err', [':err'=> $_body]);
            }
        }

        return parent::add($level, $message, $values, $additional);
    }

    public function add_exception($e, $error_level = Log::ERROR){
        return $this->add($error_level, Kohana_Exception::text($e), Array(),Array('exception'=>$e));
    }
    public static function catch_ex($ex, $error_level = Log::ERROR){
        return Kohana::$log->add_exception($ex, $error_level);
    }

    public static function msg($msg, $error_level = Log::ERROR) {
        return Kohana::$log->add($error_level, $msg);
    }
}
```